# What's wrong with this query?

Tags: php, user-registration

i'm trying to define a User registration class and this is the function i have for now

```
 <?php

///// SE SUPONE QUE AQUI EL USUARIO YA HA INTRODUCIDO SUS DATOS DE REGISTRO


/* Conectando la Base de Datos */
include("includes/basedatos.php");

require_once("includes/funciones.php");

class registro_usuarios
{

    var $pass;
    var $email;
    var $nombre;

     public function tratandovariables()
    {

        /* Eliminando Caracteres Especiales */
        $password = htmlspecialchars($_POST['pass']);
        $mail = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['mail']));
        $nombre = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['nombre']));

        if (preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]{3,20}$/", $nombre))
        {
            /* Asignando Valor */
            $this->pass = md5($password);
            $this->email = $mail;
            $this->nombre = $nombre;
        }
        else
        {
            echo "El nombre de usuario no es válido<br>";
            exit;
        }
    }

    public function register()
    {
        $this->tratandovariables();




        /* Comprobando si existe el usuario */
        $check = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE alias = '$this->nombre'";
        $qry = mysql_query($check);

        /* La compracion */
            if (mysql_num_rows($qry))
            {
                echo "Lo sentimos, el nombre de usuario ya esta registrado.<br />";
                mysql_free_result($qry);
                return false;
            } else
            {





                $insert = "INSERT INTO usuarios (alias, pass, email, fid, fechar, ultima, img_src, reputacion) VALUES ('".$this->nombre."','".$this->pass."','".$this->email."','-1', 'NOW()', 'NOW()',' ', '0' )";
                $qry = mysql_query($insert);
                    if(mysql_affected_rows())
                    {
                        echo "El Usuario $this->nombre se Registro Correctamente";
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "Error Ingresando datos";
                        return false;
                    }
                return false;
            }
    }

}
?>
```

And the problem it's that i'm allways given this error (entering a simple varchar through a form with no weird chars):

**Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/piscolab/public_html/keepyourlinks.com/Recetas/registro.php  on line 52
El Usuario toni se Registro Correctamente**

- $this->nombre has a not null value (checked)
- Database its empty, so there should be never results.
- The problem it's that the script goes on and pretends that user has been registered, even shows the name! and there is not an update on database..

I just can't see the problem.. can you?

thank you!

Comment: Can you post line 52 from registro.php? I see no mysql_fetch_array here. Actually, post line 51, where you execute the query. show the exact query. Also, you can try to just add " or die(mysql_error())" behind the mysql_query() function (if you use it) to see if the query has a fault (such as a bad table name).

Comment: Wow, You should be aware that you're wide open to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks, right?  Either escape your input (via `mysql_real_escape_string`) or use parameterized queries (the better alternative)...

Comment: MySQL only speaks English. </cheap_humor>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, thank you very much for helping me,

it seems that there was a different error (with a atribute name, tipical...) but stills worthy because found out about those errors..

If some one needs it, the class code: (adapt your atributes)

```
class registro_usuarios
{

    var $pass;
    var $email;
    var $nombre;

     public function tratandovariables()
    {

        /* Eliminando Caracteres Especiales */
        $password = htmlspecialchars($_POST['pass']);
        $mail = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['mail']));
        $nombre = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['nombre']));

        if (preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]{3,20}$/", $nombre))
        {
            /* Asignando Valor */
            $this->pass = md5($password);
            $this->email = $mail;
            $this->nombre = $nombre;
        }
        else
        {
            echo "El nombre de usuario no es válido<br>";
            exit;
        }
    }

    public function register()
    {
        $this->tratandovariables();




        /* Comprobando si existe el usuario */
        $check = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE alias = '".$this->nombre."'";
        $qry = mysql_query($check);

        /* La compracion */
            if (mysql_num_rows($qry))
            {
                echo "Lo sentimos, el nombre de usuario ya esta registrado.<br />";
                mysql_free_result($qry);
                return false;
            } else
            {





                $insert = "INSERT INTO usuarios (alias, pass, mail, fid, fechar, ultima, img_src, reputacion) VALUES ('".$this->nombre."','".$this->pass."','".$this->email."','-1', NOW(), NOW(),' ', 0 )";
                $qry = mysql_query($insert);
                    if(mysql_affected_rows())
                    {
                        echo "El Usuario $this->nombre se Registro Correctamente";
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "Error Ingresando datos";
                        return false;
                    }
                return false;
            }
    }

}
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

remove the quotes from around 'now()' else you are inserting as a string instead of MySQL timestamp

Answer (score 0):

use concatenation here :

```
/* Comprobando si existe el usuario */
    $check = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE alias = '".$this->nombre."'";
```

Comment: But really, **stop using string manipulation** and use placeholders/parametrized-queries.

Comment: True, I just pointed one error. PDO should be a better choice to handle DB (object orientation). http://php.net/manual/fr/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 0):

The [PHP manual says](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php):

> resource mysql_query ( string $query
>   [, resource $link_identifier ] )
>   mysql_query() sends a unique query
>   (multiple queries are not supported)
>   to the currently active database on
>   the server that's associated with the
>   specified link_identifier.

If you do not have a "currently active database" then your mysql_* calls will fail.  It's always best practice to supply the MySQL connection link identifier with your calls.

Where are you calling mysql_connect?

Answer (score -1):

Try this one instead;

```
$check = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE alias = '".$this->nombre."'";
```

And I don't see any mysql_fetch_array() statement in your code.

Comment: ok, did the concatenation, 'mysql_fetch_array()' where shall i place it?

Comment: Your error implies you are already using it somewhere. And this answer is not the problem, as stated by Rocket in the similar answer.

Comment: But really, **stop using string manipulation** and use placeholders/parametrized-queries.

Comment: $check = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE alias = '$this->nombre'"; is perfectly valid and will produce the proper query except in the case where a ' character is present.  In that case both solutions will fail without adding cslashes.

Comment: There is no need to add a mysql_fetch_array() statement since you are not fetching something from database, you are putting a record.
 
$qry = mysql_query($insert) or die(mysql_error());

Try this one and see if it gives any errors.